# curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_easy_header on Raspbery pi

Tags: curl, raspberry-pi, quic, http3

I tried to install "HTTP3 (and QUIC)" on my Raspbery. This is a website which I was following along and I tried "ngtcp2 version": https://curl.se/docs/http3.html.
Here is instructions for build:
Build (patched) OpenSSL

% git clone --depth 1 -b openssl-3.0.0+quic https://github.com/quictls/openssl
% cd openssl
% ./config enable-tls1_3 --prefix=
% make
% make install
Build nghttp3

% cd ..
% git clone https://github.com/ngtcp2/nghttp3
% cd nghttp3
% autoreconf -fi
% ./configure --prefix= --enable-lib-only
% make
% make install
Build ngtcp2

% cd ..
% git clone https://github.com/ngtcp2/ngtcp2
% cd ngtcp2
% autoreconf -fi
% ./configure PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/lib/pkgconfig:/lib/pkgconfig LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/lib" --prefix= --enable-lib-only
% make
% make install
Build curl

% cd ..
% git clone https://github.com/curl/curl
% cd curl
% autoreconf -fi
% LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/lib" ./configure --with-openssl= --with-nghttp3= --with-ngtcp2=
% make
% make install

During the build and after I didn't get any errors. But when I try to curl I get this error: "curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_easy_header". Can you help with my situation?

Comment: curl_easy_header is located in libcurl.so.4. Check that your curl have access to this file which you built and not the system one. This also happens if you build it with LDFLAGS in one directory prefix but later you moved it to somewhere else.